# What do these values for creating a line in tkinter mean?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I recently started working on tkinter in python and I'm not able to understand what these values (108,120,320,40) mean for creating a line ?

```
root = Tk()

c = Canvas(root, bg ="yellow",
       height = 250, width = 300)
line = c.create_line(108, 120,320, 40,fill ="green")
c.pack()
root=mainloop()
```

Comment: The coordinates of the two end points of the line.

Comment: This can be answered by reading existing documentation.

Answer (score 0):

line = c.create_line(start line x-axis, start line y-axis, end line x-axis, end line y-axis,fill ="green")

```
line = c.create_line(108, 120,320, 40,fill ="green")
```